# moving a button using a timer

Tags: c#, forms, button, timer

I have four buttons that are called "ship1,ship2" etc.
I want them to move to the right side of the form (at the same speed and starting at the same time), and every time I click in one "ship", all the ships should stop.

I know that I need to use a timer (I have the code written that uses threading, but it gives me troubles when stopping the ships.) I don't know how to use timers.

I tried to read the timer info in MDSN but I didn't understand it.
So u can help me?

HERES the code using threading.
**I don't want to use it. I need to use a TIMER! (I posted it here because it doesnt give me to post without any code**

```
    private bool flag = false;
    Thread thr;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flag = false;
        thr = new Thread(Go);
        thr.Start();

    }

    private delegate void moveBd(Button btn);

    void moveButton(Button btn)
    {
        int x = btn.Location.X;
        int y = btn.Location.Y;
        btn.Location = new Point(x + 1, y);
    }

    private void Go()
    {
        while (((ship1.Location.X + ship1.Size.Width) < this.Size.Width)&&(flag==false))
        {
            Invoke(new moveBd(moveButton), ship1);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("U LOOSE");

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flag = true;
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be homework\assignment.  I would update your tags if it is.

Comment: Wow. You wont be able to click a button like that. You are blocking the main thread which is the UI thread. Use a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.71).aspx) with the elapsed event. The problem is you are not going to get a fluid movement unless you have a very short `Interval` like 0.04 seconds (25 FPS). If you are making a game then check out [XNA](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/index.shtml)

Comment: @zeencat it isn't. I'm trying to build a game.

Comment: If you're building a game can I recommend [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) over a WinForms app? It will make building this game a whole lot easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you googled [`Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)?

You can start a timer via:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.Interval = 1000; //one second
timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Start();
```

You'll need an event handler to handle the `Elapsed` event which is where you'll put the code to handle moving the 'Button':

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)  
{
      MoveButton();       
}
```

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Timer would be a better choice here as otherwise a check for InvokeRequired is almost inevitable on the Timer_Elapsed event to avoid a cross thread exception. Otherwise agree.

Comment: @Duane and when i want it to stop moving, How do i stop the clock?

Comment: `timer.Stop()`; or `timer.Enabled = false;`